# Non realbasic ActiveX controls in Realbasic projects

Tags: vb6, activex, redistributable, realbasic

Realbasic allows you to include e.g an MS Flexgrid control in your Realbasic project and use it as though it were a native control. Does the end user need to have this control installed already and if not and realbasic includes it in the build are there licensing issues?
I have vb6 and can distribute this control legally with a vb6 application dos this alter things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redistributable license for MS Controls is AFAIK not limited to one particular development platform though you would need to check the DEV license agreement for details.

As MSFlexgrid is an ActiveX control it will still be needed and need to be registered as such using regsvr32.

Comment: OK that's interesting, thanks for the information. I think I understand you. I presume you can use Inno to do this exactly as it does for vb6 applications

Comment: Yes register them in the Run Section of the Inno script using the /REGSERVER switch and uninstall in the [RunUninstall] section.